# portable database column names

Tags: database, syntax, portability, restrictions

I am designing a relational database schema that may be ported to multiple database platforms--SQLite3, PostgreSQL and MySQL and possibly others.

I would like to create table names that would be portable across all the database platforms.  What are naming restrictions should I follow?

- What characters are allowed?
- What characters are allowed to begin the name?
- What is the maximum length?
- Are there other restrictions I should be aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{,9}$/` is generally safe.

Comment: Even SQL-86 allowed (mandated) 18 characters for object names - it might only have mandated 8 characters for schema names.  More recently, you can usually use 31 characters for object names.

Comment: If for some management reason you have to deal with .dbf files, you only get 10 characters to play with.

Comment: Just to be clear you are suggesting names that match the given regular expression.  What is the "{,9}" mean?

Comment: A variable 0 to 9 repeats of the immediately-preceding expression. So, 1 to 10 characters (although you have deeper problems if you use less than 3 [other than "id"]).